# Google Script copy and paste as values debug

Tags: date, google-apps-script, copy-paste

Looking to

1. Find cell in first row that matches yesterday's date (this part works)
2. Select column that cell belongs to
3. Copy entire column and paste as values

Not sure where the code is breaking

```
function CopyandPasteasValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; 
  // sheet is the first worksheet in the spreadsheet

  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
  yesterday.setHours(3,0,0,0); //comparison doesn't seem to work without this

  for(var i=0; i< 26; i++) {
     
    var cell = sheet.getRange(1,i+2); //start getting sheet date at cell C1
    var sheetdate = cell.getValue();

    if(sheetdate.valueOf()  == yesterday.valueOf()) {

      // if there's a match, set the col
      var col = (i);
      
      // copy column and paste as values -- BELOW DOESN"T WORK --
      function copyandpastescol() {
        sheet.getRange(1, col+2, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).activate();
        sheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you call `copyandpastescol()`?

Comment: What is it not doing? Do you get any errors? What is it doing instead of what you want it to?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat - duh... removed the function. That solved it. OMG. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Duh... didn't need the extra function! Thanks...

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function CopyandPasteasValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
  // sheet is the first worksheet in the spreadsheet

  
  // set and store a date object for today
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
  yesterday.setHours(3,0,0,0);

  // iterate the values in the range object
  for(var i=0; i< 26; i++) {
     
    var cell = sheet.getRange(1,i+2); //start getting sheet date at cell C1
    var sheetdate = cell.getValue();

    // Compare only values of the objects
    if(sheetdate.valueOf()  == yesterday.valueOf()) {

      // if there's a match, set the col
      var col = (i+2);
      
      // copy column and paste as values
      sheet.getRange(1, col, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).activate();
      sheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
     
    }
  }
}
```